# Why is the response object from JavaScript fetch API a promise?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, fetch-api

When requesting from a server with JavaScript fetch API, you have to do something like

```
fetch(API)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Here, `response.json()` is resolving its promise.

The thing is that if you want to catch `404`'s errors, you have to resolve the response promise and then reject the fetch promise, because you'll only end in `catch` if there's been a network error. So the fetch call becomes something like

```
fetch(API)
  .then(response => response.ok ? response.json() : response.json().then(err => Promise.reject(err)))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

This is something much harder to read and reason about. So my question is: why is this needed? What's the point of having a promise as a response value? Are there any better ways to handle this?

Comment: The response object is not a promise. It's a response, with a `json` (and method among others which returns a promise. Is your question why `json()` returns a promise?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but you might want to look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32516463/3887516)

Comment: Do you really need the content of the 404 response as your error? If not, there are simpler ways to achieve what you want. If you do, I don't see anything wrong with how `fetch` works.

Comment: Yes, I need that. There's nothing wrong with fetch, just that I wanted to know how it works under the hood.

Comment: I find this conversation (response promise, fetch promise??) confusing.  There is only one promise object - that returned by `fetch()`. This promise's `.then` method maps it to the return value of the function passed to `.then`.  In the first case, the function returns with `response.json()`.   Since this is a value, not a promise, the original promise gets resolved with this value.  In the second case, `.then` [conditionally] maps the original promise to a rejected promise, so the original promise gets rejected with whatever cause was passed to the rejected promise.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @caasjj: `response.json()` does return a promise as well (as it waits for the body to load)

Comment: @Bergi - thanks.  found it (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json), for anyone else equally confused.

Comment: @torazaburo is right, my question is why ``response.json()`` returns a promise, I'll edit the question. @Bergi has answered why it returns a promise but I'll keep the question open for a while because I would really appreciate to see how people is using and reasoning about fetch responses.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does .json() return a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555031/why-does-json-return-a-promise)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If your question is "why does `response.json()` return a promise?" then @Bergi provides the clue in comments: "it waits for the body to load".

If your question is "why isn't `response.json` an attribute?", then that would have required `fetch` to delay returning its response until the body had loaded, which might be OK for some, but not everyone.

This polyfill should get you what you want:

```
var fetchOk = api => fetch(api)
  .then(res => res.ok ? res : res.json().then(err => Promise.reject(err)));
```

then you can do:

```
fetchOk(API)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The reverse cannot be polyfilled.

Answer (score 4):

Because somtimes we need a **precise control for the loading process** (from recieving the first piece of data to recieving the last one).

In actual world, json may not be a good example cause it's reletively samll. But imaging a situation where a large picture is loaded gruadually (from mosaic to clear). In that case, it is too late to inform the program when the data recieving has done completely.

Since fetch() is a relatively low level api, otherwise you could use axios or so on.