# Why does .json() return a promise, but not when it passes through .then()?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, fetch-api

I've been messing around with the `fetch()` api recently, and noticed something which was a bit quirky.

```
let url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/6";

let iterator = fetch(url);

iterator
  .then(response => {
      return {
          data: response.json(),
          status: response.status
      }
  })
  .then(post => document.write(post.data));
;
```

`post.data` returns a `Promise` object.
http://jsbin.com/wofulo/2/edit?js,output

However if it is written as:

```
let url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/6";

let iterator = fetch(url);

iterator
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(post => document.write(post.title));
;
```

`post` here is a standard `Object` which you can access the title attribute.
http://jsbin.com/wofulo/edit?js,output

So my question is: why does `response.json` return a promise in an object literal, but return the value if just returned?

Comment: This makes sense when you consider the `response.json()` promise might be rejected if the response is not valid JSON.

Comment: The value is returned because promise has been resolved passing the value in response.json(). Now the value is available in then method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the response object from JavaScript fetch API a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721850/why-is-the-response-object-from-javascript-fetch-api-a-promise)

Comment: Note that despite the method being named json(), the result is not JSON. It returns a promise which resolves with a JavaScript object that is the result of parsing the body text as JSON. This object could be anything that can be represented by JSON — an object, an array, a string, a number... reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json

Comment: There are two parts to this question: (a) why does `json()` return a promise at all, and (b) why does returning a promise in a `.then` callback unwrap the promise for the next `.then` callback. Both should have been asked as separate questions. It’s a shame this question has been such a persistent dupehammer target; it hasn’t been very well asked in the first place.

Comment: @user3840170 For (a) you can also use https://stackoverflow.com/q/32721850/ as a dupe target

Answer (score 283, accepted):

> Why does `response.json` return a promise?

Because you receive the `response` as soon as all headers have arrived. Calling `.json()` gets you another promise for the body of the http response that is yet to be loaded. See also [Why is the response object from JavaScript fetch API a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32721850/1048572).

> Why do I get the value if I return the promise from the `then` handler?

Because [that's how promises work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572). The ability to return promises from the callback and get them adopted is their most relevant feature, it makes them chainable without nesting.

You can use

```
fetch(url).then(response => 
    response.json().then(data => ({
        data: data,
        status: response.status
    })
).then(res => {
    console.log(res.status, res.data.title)
}));
```

or any other of the [approaches to access previous promise results in a .then() chain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572) to get the response status after having awaited the json body. Modern version using `await` (inside an `async` function):

```
const response = await fetch(url);
const data = await response.json();
console.log(response.status, data.title);
```

Also, you might want to check the status (or just `.ok`) *before* reading the response, it might not be JSON at all.

Comment: It seems weird that I can't just wait for the data to return using a Promise, and when it's arrived convert it to json? Or perhaps in that case I could just use `JSON.parse()` instead of `res.json()` ??

Comment: @Kokodoko `res.json()` basically is a shortcut for `res.text().then(JSON.parse)`. Both wait for the data using a promise and parse the json.

Comment: @Bergi, hi, sorry I faced some confusion, that is, by using then(res=>res.json()) we send another request to get JSON?

Comment: @mirzhal No, there is no other request. It just is reading (asynchronously!) the rest of the response.

Answer (score 25):

This difference is due to the behavior of Promises more than `fetch()` specifically.

When a `.then()` callback returns an additional `Promise`, the next `.then()` callback in the chain is essentially bound to that Promise, receiving its resolve or reject fulfillment and value.

The 2nd snippet could also have been written as:

```
iterator.then(response =>
    response.json().then(post => document.write(post.title))
);
```

In both this form and yours, the value of `post` is provided by the Promise returned from `response.json()`.

---

When you return a plain `Object`, though, `.then()` considers that a successful result and resolves itself immediately, similar to:

```
iterator.then(response =>
    Promise.resolve({
      data: response.json(),
      status: response.status
    })
    .then(post => document.write(post.data))
);
```

`post` in this case is simply the `Object` you created, which holds a `Promise` in its `data` property. The wait for that promise to be fulfilled is still incomplete.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the above answers here is how you might handle a 500 series response from your api where you receive an error message encoded in json:

```
function callApi(url) {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json().then(response => ({ response }));
      }

      return response.json().then(error => ({ error }));
    })
  ;
}

let url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/6';

const { response, error } = callApi(url);
if (response) {
  // handle json decoded response
} else {
  // handle json decoded 500 series response
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Also, what helped me understand this particular scenario that you described is the Promise API [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#return_value), specifically where it explains how the promised returned by the `then` method will be resolved differently depending on what the **handler fn** returns:

> if the handler function:
>
> - returns a value: p gets fulfilled with the returned value as its value.
> - doesn't return anything: p gets fulfilled with undefined as its value.
> - throws an error: p gets rejected with the thrown error as its value.
> - returns an already fulfilled promise: p gets fulfilled with that promise's value as its value.
> - returns an already rejected promise: p gets rejected with that promise's value as its value.
> - returns another pending promise: p is pending and becomes fulfilled/rejected with that promise's value as its value immediately after that promise becomes fulfilled/rejected.

Answer (score -1):

```
iterator
  .then(response => {
      return {
          data: response.json(),
          status: response.status
      }
  })
  .then(post => document.write(post.data));
;
```

when you use `data: response.json()`, you are not returning a resolved/rejected response that would be a normal JS object or an error. Since response.json() returns a promise and on returning that you get the resolved state. Where post.data is the **promise object**.

when you write `return response.json()` you get access to the resolved response with the title property in the returned normal JS object.

Answer (score -2):

The *json()* method is available on all *fetch()* function. The *json()* method returns a *Promise*. Remember, when returning a *Promise*, it is still **pending** because it is asynchronous (assuming the data is not there yet). So to get the data **AFTER** using the *json()* method, you need to use another *then()* method so it will just return the data after it arrives.

To answer your question, It is what it is, its just the way of doing that.

Its like Promise ---> Another Promise ----> data