# Generators + Promises promise resolve with ok status but in console Promise {<pending>}

Tags: promise, generator

```
function foo() {
  return fetch('https://central.wordcamp.org/wp-json/wp/v2/wordcamps');
}

function* main() {
  try {
    var text = yield foo();
    var d = text.json();
    console.log(d); //Promise {<pending>} 
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
var it = main();

var p = it.next().value;

// wait for the `p` promise to resolve
p.then(function (text) { 
    it.next(text);
  },
  function (err) {
    it.throw(err);
  }
);
```

promise result ok but in console `Promise {<pending>}`

[SCREEN SHOT](http://prntscr.com/j2jkik)
Anybody can help me where the problem.
[BOOK REFERNCE](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/ch4.md)

you can check helping detail in this book search Generators + Promises.

Comment: First of all, stop using generators with a promise runner as a lame fill-in for `async`/`await`!

Comment: This is expected. [`text.json()` does return another promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37555031/1048572).