# How to resolve a promise and get data from [[PromiseValue]]

Tags: javascript

Could you please  help me solving this. How can I access the values in PromiseValue?. I m getting

[[PromiseStatus]]
:
"resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]
:

Here is my code

```
function getMovies(searchTerm){
        fetch('http://www.omdbapi.com/?t='+searchTerm+'&apikey=xxxxxxx')
        .then((resp) =>{console.log(resp.json())
        })

        .catch((err) =>{console.log(err)
        });
    }


})
```

I am getting the response (resp) but I assume the promise is not done yet? But what additional .then do I have to write to finally get my final data which is currently within [[PromiseValue]]

Comment: The same way you resolve any other promise: `.then(resp => resp.json()).then(json => console.log(json))`;

Comment: Related: [Why does .json() return a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37555031/218196)