# Promise.all returning empty objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get multiple data objects from The Movie Database at once using `Promise.all`. After I loop through all the results of the `fetch` call, and use `.json()` on each bit of data, I tried to log it to the console. However, rather than an array of objects with data, I'm getting an array of `Promises`. Nested in the promises, I can see my data, but I'm clearly missing a step in order to have an array of data objects, instead of just `Promises`.

What am I missing here?

```
 //store movie API URLs into meaningful variables
    const trending = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/day?api_key=${API_KEY}`;
    const topRated = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`;
    const nowPlaying = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`;
    const upcoming = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`;
    //create an array of urls to fetch data from
    const allMovieURLs = [trending, topRated, nowPlaying, upcoming];
    const promiseURLs = allMovieURLs.map(url => fetch(url));
    Promise.all(promiseURLs)
      .then(responses => responses.map(url => url.json()))
      .then(dataArr => console.log(dataArr));
  };
```

Comment: It's not the problem, but that code makes two common mistakes that may hit you at some point. 1. You're not checking that the requests succeed. This is such a common error (in my view, an error in the `fetch` API) that I [wrote it up](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) on my anemic little blog. Check `.ok` on the responses. 2. You're not handling rejection of your `Promise.all` promise, and not passing it to something that will handle it. You need to either handle it or pass the promise on to something that will.

Comment: closely related: [Why does .json() return a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37555031/1048572)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This is an awesome addition to a problem I didn't even know I was having. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your `.then(responses => responses.map(url => url.json()))` resolves to an array of Promises, so you need to call `Promise.all` again if you want to wait for all to resolve:

```
Promise.all(promiseURLs)
  .then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(url => url.json())))
  .then(dataArr => console.log(dataArr));
```

Or, you might consider using just one `Promise.all`, and having each URL `fetch` and the `json`, that way some items aren't idle in the middle of script execution:

```
const allMovieURLs = [trending, topRated, nowPlaying, upcoming];
const promiseURLs = allMovieURLs.map(url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json()));
Promise.all(promiseURLs)
  .then(dataArr => console.log(dataArr));
```

Comment: I didn't realize that `Body.json` also returned a `Promise`! Your explanation was simple and concise, and this has solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Probably worth pointing out the missing `.ok` check (I've done so now in a comment on the question).

Answer (score 4):

try doing it this way

```
const promiseURLs = allMovieURLs.map(url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json()));
Promise.all(promiseURLs)
  .then(responses => responses.forEach(response => { console.log(response)})
```