# Why i have make another .then to pull a promiseValue from fetch promise

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

[image]

Hello. First .then is resolved and have a value response. Why if i log res.text it is just a promise, and when i make another then with the same return , next .then with the same res.text it's a string now??
May someone explain it for me:)?

Comment: short answer is - this is how `fetch` is specified and implemented - so, the reason you have to "make another .then" is because that's how you use fetch API

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does .json() return a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555031/why-does-json-return-a-promise)

Answer (score 1):

The [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) function returns a Promise that resolves with a [`Body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body) response.

Paraphrased from [Mozilla: Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and [Mozilla: Body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body):

> The fetch() method... returns a Promise that resolves to the Response to that request, whether it is successful or not... Once a Response is retrieved, there are a number of methods available to define what the body content is and how it should be handled.

If you then navigate to the documentation for [`Body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body) you can see that it has a number of methods on it. The [`Body.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body#Methods) method:

> Takes a Response stream and reads it to completion. It returns a promise that resolves with a USVString (text). The response is always decoded using UTF-8.

The behavior you've described is how the `fetch` API is expected to behave.

Answer (score 0):

The Fetch API returns a promise which resolves to a Response. The Response itself has a text() method which returns a promise as well. You can use this method to read the Response-Stream as a text. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response