# How to read a JSON object that currently stringifies as "Object Promise"

Tags: node.js, discord, node-modules

My Discord bot continuously sends [Object Promised] when I use

```
const DabiImages = require("dabi-images");
const DabiClient = new DabiImages.Client();
DabiClient.sfw.real.random().then(json => {
    console.log(json);
 }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
 });
```

I was wondering how I can fix this, as I'm not sure.

Comment: I think I saw the answer to this recently. Your DabiClient returns a promise, and when that is resolved it returns a JSON object, which itself is a promise. That needs to be resolved too, presumably also with a `.then()`.

Comment: Maybe this is the answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37555432

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the comments on this already answer the question but you could..

```
const DabiImages = require('dabi-images')

const DabiClient = new DabiImages.Client()

const main = async () => {
    const dabiJson = await DabiClient.sfw.real.random()
    console.log(dabiJson)
}

main()
```

Also worth mentioning, that the `sfw` doesn't exist

Comment: Yep, I just erased the "n" to avoid unwanted judgment! But yes this did work thank you very very much!

Comment: Haha. Totally fine. If this worked please accept it! Cheers