# React: Can't create li element because Promise(<pending>);

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I cannot figure out how to access this Promise object. How to map this promise? And why my async/await function is returning a promise and not a result object?
Any feedback appreciated.

```
Promise {<pending>}
 [[Prototype]]: Promise
 [[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
 [[PromiseResult]]: Array(2)
   0: "hey"
   1: "bye"
   length: 2[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState();
  const [chat, setChat] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {...}, []);
***//getting previous chat for new users.***

  useEffect(async () => {
    let mounted = true;
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/main_chat").then(
      (res) => {
        if (mounted) {
          setChat(res.json());
        }
      }
    );

    return () => (mounted = false);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {...},[socket]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    socket.emit("sentFromClient", text);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>{console.log(chat)}</ul>
      <input value={text} onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}></input>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick()}>enter</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Note: `useEffect` shouldn't have an async callback. It should have an async function inside it that gets called. Otherwise there are unexpected side-effects.

Comment: got the same result :(

Comment: Yeah, that wasn't an answer, just a general comment about the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetch` returns a Promise, which you wait for, but then `res.json()` returns another Promise, which you don't wait for. So that Promise is passed to `setChat` and becomes the value of `chat`.

You're also mixing up `await` and `.then`, which do the same thing, so you should probably only use one or the other.

With `await`:

```
const response = await fetch(...)
const json = await response.json()
setChat(json)
```

With `.then`:

```
fetch(...)
    .then(response => {
        return response.json()
    })
    .then(json => {
        setChat(json) 
    })
```

Finally, you're right to check if you're still mounted before calling `setChat`, but passing an async function to `useEffect` won't work because you need to return the cleanup function (`() => (mounted = false)`), and async functions return Promises. So:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true
    const getChat = async () => {
        await whatever...
        if (mounted) setChat(something)
    }
    getChat()
    return () => (mounted = false)
})
```

Or

```
useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true
    fetch(...).then(chat => {
        if (mounted) setChat(chat)
    })
    return () => (mounted = false)
})
```

Comment: I wouldn't call that variable `json` as that's definitely what it's not at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You are using both `.then()` and `async\await` which is a bit confusing.
Maybe you should start by removing`console.log()` from the returned JSX expression.
Then, inside your useEffect hook, update it to this

```
useEffect(async () => {
    let mounted = true;
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/main_chat")
        if (mounted) {
         // consol.log(response) here should give you the value returned by the API
          setChat(response);
        }
// Not sure why are you returning this function definition
    return () => (mounted = false);
  }, []);
```

Comment: You forgot the `await response.json()` though

Comment: @Bergi setChat(await response.json() ) worked

Comment: why .json() is a promise idk

Comment: @NewGuy9000 See [Why does .json() return a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37555031/1048572)