# Attach request result to json response

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, fetch-api

So this is the code:

```js
let pending_task_list = fetch("/tasks", {
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json"
    }
}).then(function(res) {
    return {succeeded: res.ok, pending_message: res.json()};
}).then(function(data){
    let message = data.pending_message;
    return {succeeded: data.succeeded, message: message};
});
```

...

```js
let task_list = await pending_task_list;
```

Now, `task_list.message` is still a promise. How can resolve the promise given by `res.json()` in this case.

This question is different from [Why does .json() return a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555031/why-does-json-return-a-promise) because I am looking for an answer on how to compose a value that has become available, with a value that is not yet available. While the particular application is to get `json` data back, the question covers a broader topic about promises and async functions in general.

Comment: "*This question is different from [Why does .json() return a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555031/why-does-json-return-a-promise)*" - I don't see how. The answer there does exactly what you are looking for. Even if you were asking the "*broader topic about promises and async functions in general*", [the canonical question on that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572) was already linked there.