# If we typically need a promise to be handled before moving on, why not return an already-handled response instead of a promised response?

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I've been reading quite a bit and watching videos, but unfortunately haven't found an answer to my question. This makes me think that my question is misguided, but I'd like to know why. (Note: I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721850/why-is-the-response-object-from-javascript-fetch-api-a-promise) helpful, but the answers didn't seem to address my curiosity.)

---

If I understand correctly, promises don't really function like this:

**Friend:** Listen, by the end of the day, I'm going to get you a computer. That's a promise.

**Me:** Fantastic! While you're doing that, I'll get a lot of other things done.

**Friend (at the end of the day):** Here's this box. You just need to open (handle) it.

I open the box and, if it's empty, I know that her promise has failed (rejected). If there's a computer inside, I know her promise was successful. And, if there's a note inside that says, "Still working on fulfilling this promise," I know that her promise is still pending.

---

Instead, promises seem to function like this:

**Friend:** Listen, by the end of the day, I'm going to get you a computer. That's a promise.

**Me:** Okay, I'd like that computer as soon as possible because all my tasks today are contingent on that. I need to send several emails, which will require that computer. I need to research fetch requests, which will also require what you're promising. Then I need to ask a question on StackOverflow, which will definitely require that machine. So, I'm just going to wait until your promise is successful or failed (or you tell me that you need more time).

Then, the friend returns with that same box from the first scenario so that I need to first open the box (or handle the promise) first before any further tasks can be performed.

---

So, then, my question is, if we need to wait on a promise response, why does that response not come back pre-handled? In other words, why does my friend hand me a box that I must open instead of handing me the computer or telling me that they failed (or letting me know they need more time)?

When I make a fetch request, I can't just use the response. I need to `json()` it first. Or, I need to `then()` and `catch()` it first. Why do we return promised data instead of the data itself (if successful, of course)?

I hope this question makes sense. I look forward to having my assumption(s) corrected.

Comment: You can't return the data itself.  The function returns long before the data is available.  That's how asynchronous operations work in Javascript.  So, at the time the function is returning, the data has not yet arrived.  So, you return a promise which allows the caller to hook a `.then()` listener to the promise and get notified when the data is actually ready.

Comment: "*When I make a fetch request, I can't just use the response. I need to `json()` it first*" but what if you're fetching an image or plain text? Why you'd you want to call `.json()` on that and get an error? *that* is the reason you don't want it pre-handled - `fetch` doesn't *know* what you want to do with the data. Even if you're getting JSON you might even still want it in text format for one reason or another. Maybe you're just getting a .json file and storing it in a database, for example.

Comment: @VLAZ, I didn't mean to imply that every response would go through .json(), but after re-reading my question, that wasn't clear. Either way, your point is absolutely valid, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I make a fetch request, I can't just use the response. I need to json() it first. Or, I need to then() and catch() it first. Why do we return promised data instead of the data itself (if successful, of course)?

You can't return the data itself.  The host function itself returns long before the data is available.  That's how non-blocking, asynchronous operations work in Javascript.  So, at the time the function is returning, the data has not yet arrived.  So, instead you return a promise which allows the caller to hook a `.then()` listener to the promise and get notified when the data is actually ready or a `.catch()` listener to see if there is an error.

Let's look at a simple example.  Let's say you have an asynchronous operation that returns you some value.  You want to create another function that squares that value and returns it.

```js
// get random number between 0 and 9999
function rand() {
     return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
}

function getValue() {
     console.log("5");
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         console.log("6");
         setTimeout(() => {
             console.log("7");
             resolve(rand());                 
             console.log("8");
         }, 500);
     });
}

function getSquaredValue() {
     console.log("3");
     return getValue().then(val => {
         console.log("4");
         return val * val;
     });
}

console.log("1");
getSquaredValue().then(val => {
    console.log("got value");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
console.log("2");
```

The output from running that script is this:

```
1
3
5
6
2
7
8
4
got value
```

Study this order to follow the flow through these asynchronous operations.  It should be no surprise that it goes 1, 3, 5, 6 as that's the order of function calls.

But, now look at what comes next.  It's 2.  That means that `getSquaredValue()` has already returned.  But, we don't yet have our random number or its squared result yet.  That's why you need promises.  You return the promise and the caller attaches their `.then()` listener.  Some unknown time in the future, when the value is finally available, it will notify that `.then()` listener and tell you what the final value is.

Since you were creating some analogies, I'll make one of my own.  Suppose you are building a storage shed.  You determine that you need a new hammer so you order one on Amazon.

In our world, the delivery of a new package from Amazon is non-blocking and asynchronous.  You submit the order on Monday and specify one day delivery.  You don't have to just sit there by the door for a whole day waiting for the package and doing nothing else.  Instead, you submit the order and immediately go about your other projects, eating meals, etc... as if nothing happened.  Then, in the background (without any further attention from you), the whole process of procuring that product, packing it into a box and sending it to you is going on.

Then, sometime later (you specified next day delivery, so it should be sometime the next day), the doorbell rings indicating a package delivery.  When you have a moment in what else you were doing, you take a break from that other task and you got fetch the package from the door.

The asynchronous operation is now complete.  It notified you when it was done and you could then go fetch the value.  Meanwhile, all the time that the order was being worked on, you could be doing other things (non-blocking).

Comment: If you want to continue the hammer analogy: using `then` is just like a ToDo list of task you would get to after you get the gammer. `then(package => package.open()).then(openPackage => takeHammer(openPackage)).then(hammer => finishWork(hammer))`. Whether that happens immediately or something more urgent (mom calls to tell you about your aunt's dog's cute trick) interrupts you, you're going to go through the ToDo and finish it ASAP after the delivery.

Comment: @jfriend00, thank you! This was the best explanation that I've read in the past few years. I've read many explanations, and I've been happy that almost all of them have helped folks out, but for some reason, they just weren't clicking for me. As soon as you said, "The host function itself returns long before the data is available," this was apparently the key that I needed to open my mind. Then the code snippet was brilliant, and the hammer metaphor will now be my go-to (since I knew my own analogy was flawed, but just wasn't sure how). A well-crafted answer, thank you!

Comment: @VLAZ, thank you for your addition! I found that amendment to be helpful (and amusing :-) ).

Answer (score 1):

No, your metaphor doesn't fit. There is no "*by the end of the day*", and there is no "*box that I need to open to check whether it's empty*".

A promise is your friend telling you "*I need more time, but I promise to get this eventually*". And maybe more importantly, "*I'll tell you when I'm done*". If you want to use a box metaphor, it's more like being handed a box with a note that it will open by itself once there is a computer inside there. There is no repeated checking.

Sure, you could sit around and do nothing but wait until the box opens. But being handed a promise box means that your friend can't hand you the computer immediately but needs more time, so you should be doing something else in the meanwhile. That could be asking other friends for more computers. Or having the local library fetch you a book on promises to read so that you can start programming immediately once you got the computer (without waiting for responses to the SO question). And of course it means that you will promise the result of your work to your client, so that even if *you* have nothing else to do but wait on the computer being fetched, *they* might.

Comment: To elaborate on the computer metaphor - you'd get notified when you get one, as Bergi says. You've set out the tasks already - 1. write emails 2. research `fetch` 3. post on SO. There is indeed no continuous checking the box, as well - you don't just stand around the box and peek inside every once in a while. Once done, your friends taps you on the shoulder and says "I'm done" (promise resolved) and you start writing emails, then researching, then posting. Or your friend comes in and says "Sorry, sharks ate your computer" (promise rejected) and you potentially try to do something (`.catch`)

Comment: @Bergi, thank you for your answer. I didn't mean to imply that I was repeatedly checking the box, but your correction makes sense. Incidentally, when you say, "Or reading a book on promises so that you might not need to ask SO questions," what did you mean by this? I know that my question was downvoted (though I'm not sure why), but are you implying that I've wasted valuable SO db space with my question? I'm asking this sincerely because I don't know you and prefer to ask than assume (when it comes to human intent). Either way, I sincerely thank you for your time in formulating a response!

Comment: @MicahWierenga No, it was just meant as an example for using multiple strategies to achieve the same result (here: ask question on the web, or read a book on the topic), then use the result of the strategy that succeeded earliest. Promises are a great way to deal with the results of concurrent tasks like that.

Comment: @Bergi Makes sense. Thank you again for your helpful response!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is running synchronously, and Promise is a way to handle asnyc actions.
how do you handle it using a promise? inside the `.then()`.

```js
 ... sync code
 promise.then((someVar)=>{
     async code will run when the promise is fulfilled and someVar will be defined
 })
 ... sync code will run before the promise is fulfilled and someVar is not defined
```

you can define a function as an asynchronous function with the async/await syntax to achieve what you are looking for

```js
async function someAsyncFunction() {
   ... sync code
   let someVar = await promise();
   ... async code will run when the promise is fulfilled and someVar will be defined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your standard html + javascript site runs in effectively one thread. Long running javascript tasks will block the ui from receiving inputs or rendering updates.

Network requests can take up to several seconds. If we had to wait for the results for 3 seconds then the website would be frozen for 3 seconds. Instead, web requests are internally handled on a separate thread and the main javascript thread is notified when the web request completes (success or fail).

So we cannot wait for the request because it will freeze the site, but we also need to be able to receive the result of the web request when it arrives. The way plain old original javascript did this is through [Callback functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function).
Here is a basic example of how it can work with web requests taken from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest):

```
//This function is called when the web request completes
function reqListener () {
   console.log(this.responseText);
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
oReq.open("GET", "http://www.example.org/example.txt");
oReq.send();
```

Now, how does this fit in with promises? Well the thing is a lot of people don't like callbacks, it can be quite easy to get tangled up. Promises are effectively nice wrappers for older callback-based approaches. Promises can also be easily passed around into other functions and services and when the promise resolves all of the `.then()`'s of everything.

So the reason we cant just wait for the data is because it will freeze the site. The reason we use promises is because they are a convenient wrapper for older callback style approaches.

What if the web request is required/critical for your site? Well you still don't need to block. Simply show a loading screen and when the promise returns you can show your intended data, or an error message if it failed. Important is that while the request is pending, the site remains responsive even if there's not much to show. Mouse clicks and scrolling will register, the loading spinner will animate etc.