# async await resolve promise only if I return single value

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api

I have the followin fetch using async/await:

```
async function postData(url = "", data = {}) {
    // Default options are marked with *
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: "cors", // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
    });
    //return response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
    return {status:response.status, message:response.json()};
}
```

If I just use the commented return I correctly get the JSON returned by the API, if I use the second return response.json ends up being a

> Promise: {"Pending"}

How can I get back from the function both informations?
The API is sending me the data like this:

```
return res.status(200).json("Message to be displayed");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The `json()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) also [returns a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32721850/1048572), you need to `await` it:

```
return { status: response.status, message: await response.json() };
```

---

> If I just use the commented return I correctly get the JSON returned by the API

Presumably consuming code was awaiting it somewhere.  The overall `async` function still itself returns a `Promise` that would need to be awaited/resolved.